# Create several exposure combined density/ distribution plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
set.seed(42)
n=1000
db = data.frame(id=1:n,
                exp_1 = as.numeric(rnorm(n)),
                exp_2 = as.numeric(rnorm(n)),
                exp_3 = as.numeric(rnorm(n)), 
                exp_4=as.numeric(rnorm(n)))
label(db$exp_1)="Myx"
label(db$exp_2)="ff3"
label(db$exp_3)="poison-untitled"
label(db$exp_4)="NH3"
```

I want to create a combined density plot - with legends referring to the variable label
a plot similar to
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you could change your data to a longer format using `pivot_longer` from `tidyr`. The graph you mentioned looks like `ggpubr` so you can use `ggdensity` with `scale_fill_discrete` to modify the legend like this:

```r
set.seed(42)
n=1000
db = data.frame(id=1:n,
                exp_1 = as.numeric(rnorm(n)),
                exp_2 = as.numeric(rnorm(n)),
                exp_3 = as.numeric(rnorm(n)), 
                exp_4=as.numeric(rnorm(n)))

library(ggpubr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
db %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>%
  ggdensity(x = 'value', fill = 'name') +
  scale_fill_discrete('', labels = c('Myx', 'ff3', 'poison-untitled', 'NH3'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

If you want to change the transparency, you could use the argument `alpha` in `ggdensity`. For more info check this [documentation](https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/ggdensity.html).

Comment: Error in `pivot_longer_spec()`:
! Can't combine `exposure.1001_new` <labelled> and `exposure.1003_new` <labelled>.
✖ Some attributes are incompatible.
ℹ The author of the class should implement vctrs methods.
ℹ See <https://vctrs.r-lib.org/reference/faq-error-incompatible-attributes.html>.
Backtrace:
 1. ... %>% ggdensity(x = "value", fill = "name")
 4. tidyr:::pivot_longer.data.frame(., cols = -subnum)
 5. tidyr::pivot_longer_spec(data, spec, names_repair = names_repair, values_drop_na = values_drop_na, values_ptypes = values_ptypes, values_transform = values_transform)

Comment: Hey I replaced the variables from the sample into my own variables and got this message

Comment: Hey, What types are the columns you mentioned in your comment? Maybe they have different types.

Comment: solved it, thanks.